# Issues while converting a windows app to windows service

Tags: windows, service

I created a monitoring utility that checks cpu, ram, drive space stats and emails if the usage goes above set threshold. It works great in the system tray but I realized that the exe will stop when I log out of windows server. That led me to believe that I needed to create a windows service. I would like to use the existing GUI Form to save data to application settings and use those settings in windows service. Here are the steps I took so far,

1. Added a Windows Service class.
2. Modified the original code to get rid of any interactive items that were related to GUI Form.
3. Added the code to this class.
4. Added a Service installer.
5. Added this code to it-->

```
public ProjectInstaller()    
{      
    InitializeComponent();

    ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();

    ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

    serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

    serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;

    serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;

    serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

    serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Server Monitoring";

    this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);

    this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);      
}
```

6. Change Start up object to Utility.Program.

When I try installing this through installUtil I get this error

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Use
rs\AdminUser\Desktop\Temp\Server' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
find the file specified..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving these application settings into a file that is in the same directory as the Windows service, that is going to be your problem.  **All Windows Services are run in the C:/Windows directory** (or a sub-directory in there) so when you access files you will need to do one of two things:

### Change the executing directory

You can change the 'current directory' for the executing app back to the folder that contains the exe with the following line of code:

> System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

This will make all relative files become relative to the executable location once again.

### Make all file request full paths

This one is easier for some files than others.  System files are the hardest.  So if you are trying to get to a .config file, that's going to be a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks! where does that code from first solution go? Sorry I am new to C#.

Comment: The code can go anywhere that is guaranteed to run before your program starts trying to access files.  I usually put that in the OnStart event handler so it is executed each time the service starts up again, but you could also put it in the Main or any other place that you KNOW will get executed early on.